# Corruption Perception Index (CPI) by Transparency International

Tags: data-format, programming

I need the indeces in analyzable format, i.e. `csv`, `xls`, from the year 2005 to 2015. The results are in HTML table/PDF format on the [TI website](https://www.transparency.org/). Can anyone link a source or write a script to scrape the data?

Comment: Can you give me a direct link to the HTML data? I need that before I can answer your question. Also, http://www.fiverr.com has freelancers that do a lot of data entry and data conversion.

Comment: Found it at [https://github.com/datasets/corruption-perceptions-index](https://github.com/datasets/corruption-perceptions-index).

Comment: I think you're going to have to do a bit of work on this one, or go to fiverr.com for help.

Comment: why don't you use the link you posted? its views as HTML but its csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Github link there is a file acquire_data.r. It has the exact URLs for datafiles from 2010 to 2015.

- http://files.transparency.org/content/download/1950/12812/file/2015_CPI_DataMethodologyZIP.zip
- http://files.transparency.org/content/download/1857/12438/file/CPI2014_DataBundle.zip
- http://files.transparency.org/content/download/702/3015/file/CPI2013_DataBundle.zip
- http://files.transparency.org/content/download/533/2213/file/2012_CPI_DataPackage.zip
- http://files.transparency.org/content/download/313/1264/file/CPI2011_DataPackage.zip
- http://files.transparency.org/content/download/426/1752/CPI+2010+results_pls_standardized_data.xls

Inside those zip files are XLS files. I looked at one.

You can now copy and paste and assemble the data yourself. There are [earlier years here](http://www.transparency.org/research/cpi/cpi_early/0/). That will get you part of what you need.

For the earlier years I went to the 2009 webpage (http://www.transparency.org/research/cpi/cpi_2009/), I selected the table in my browser, and pasted the content into a text editor. From there it should be easy to save the text editor file to a .txt file, then import to Excel as comma-delimited. In the text editor data I pasted there are actually tabs between the columns, so it shouldn't be hard.